# Regex Optimization

Tags: c#, regex

The code looks silly, precompiling the Regex each time it is called and discarding the local variable. This block seems to cause some delay. Is there any better way to do this?

```
public const string REGEX_NUMERIC = @"^\-?\(?([0-9]{0,3}(\,?[0-9]{3})*(\.?[0-9]*))\)?$";

public static bool IsExactMatch(string input, string pattern)
{
    if (IsEmpty(input)) return false;
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match m = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
    if (!m.Success) return false;
    return m.Groups[0].Value == input;
}
```

Comment: Can't you simply add a `^` and `$` to the pattern so it can only ever match the *complete input*? That is, the match has to start at the start of the input and end at the end of the input.

Comment: Please don't delete your old question and repost the same one. As mentioned in the previous one, there's no point compiling the regex if it's only being used once.

Answer (score 3):

If the pattern doesn't change, you don't need to compile it every time. Make it static.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the pattern to match *the entire input*, just use [`^` and `$` anchors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#atomic_zerowidth_assertions) to your pattern.

`^` matches the start of the input, while `$` matches the end of the input. By placing these respectively before and after your actual pattern, you're only allowing matches which both *start* at the input's start and *end* at the input's end. In short: the match must cover the *entire* input.

```
var pattern = new Regex('^foo$');
Console.WriteLine(pattern.Matches('foo')); // => true
Console.WriteLine(pattern.Matches('foobar')); // => false
Console.WriteLine(pattern.Matches('lolfoo')); // => false
```

Don't reinvent the wheel! ;-)

Comment: public const string REGEX_NUMERIC = @"^\-?\(?([0-9]{0,3}(\,?[0-9]{3})*(\.?[0-9]*))\)?$";  This is the pattern I am using.

Comment: @iam Then that should "just work"™. If it doesn't, clarify your problem in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to indicate that your problem revolves around the constantly compiled regular expression.

With the assumption that you are providing different patterns to this function, why not cache the compiled Regexes?

(This would also work if you're only tossing that REGEX_NUMERIC at the function, but definitely be considered overkill.)

```
public const string REGEX_NUMERIC = @"^\-?\(?([0-9]{0,3}(\,?[0-9]{3})*(\.?[0-9]*))\)?$";
private static Dictionary<string, Regex> regexes = new Dictionary<string, Regex>();

public static bool IsExactMatch(string input, string pattern)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) return false;

    Regex regex;
    if (!regexes.TryGetValue(pattern, out regex))
    {
        regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
        regexes.Add(pattern, regex);
    }

    Match m = regex.Match(input);
    if (!m.Success) return false;
    return m.Groups[0].Value == input;
}
```